# Phonegap + Xcode WebSocket server

Tags: html, ios, xcode, cordova, websocket

I am trying to develop a PhoneGap app for the iOS. Is it possible to implement a WebSocket server and client in the native part of the app (in Xcode) to create a way for two instances of the app in different devices in a local network to communicate? The end result of the app to be developed is something similar to the app Air Sketch.

Other suggestions are appreciated. :)